# How can I prove that a cylinder is diffeomorphic to a twice-punctured $n$-sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, cylindrical-coordinates, diffeomorphism

I'm having some trouble in solving this problem:

> "Prove that the cylinder $S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic
>   to $S^n\setminus\{N,S\}$, where $N$ and $S$ are the north pole and the
>   south pole of $S^n$".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I did so thinking of $S^n\setminus\{N,S\}$ having one local paper and $S^{n-1}$ with the polar coordinates plus one coordinate for $\mathbb{R}$, but I can't find the diffeomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by “paper”?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a local chart

Comment: If we endow with the round cylinder metric on the cylinder and the round sphere metric on the punctured sphere, can we say they are also isometric working with the pullback of the diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Psi\colon&S^{n-1}\times(-1,1)&\longrightarrow&S^n\setminus\bigl\{(0,\ldots,0,\pm1)\bigr\}\\&(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)&\mapsto&\left(x_1\sqrt{1-y^2},\ldots,x_n\sqrt{1-y^2},y\right)\end{array}$$It's a diffeomorphism. Can you use it to define the diffeomorphism that your're after?

Comment: there's something I don't understand in this function's definition, because $0\in(-1,1)$, but $\psi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0)=(0,\ldots,0,1)\not\in S^n\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0,\pm 1)\}$. How can it be a diffeomorphism if it's not bijective?

Comment: @Andrew_Paste It can't. I've edited my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I tried with the following answer. Can you check that please?

Comment: @Andrew_Paste Please tell me one thing: do you agree that the map that I defined is a diffeomorphism betweem $S^{n-1}\times(-1,1)$ and $S^n\setminus\bigl\{(0,\ldots,0,\pm1\bigr\}$?

Comment: Yes I do, but I get stuck in how extend it to $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$, so I tried something else. Maybe I can use your map considering that $S^{n-1}\times(-1,1)$ and $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ are diffeomorphic. But is it so?

Comment: @Andrew_Paste Consider the map $f\colon(-1,1)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac x{1-x^2}$. It is a diffeomorphism. Therefore, $S^{n-1}\times(-1,1)$ and $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$ are diffeomorphic. Since $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb R$ and $S^n\setminus\bigl\{(0,\ldots,0,\pm1)\bigr\}$ are diffeomorphic…

Comment: Ok, so I can prove that $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times(-1,1)$ and then that $S^{n-1}\times(-1,1)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n\setminus\{N,S\}$. Since the composition of diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism, I get that $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^n\setminus\{N,S\}$.

Comment: @Andrew_Paste Yes, that's it.

Comment: That's good and I really thank you for your suggestion, but now the question is: is there a faster way to prove that two manifolds are diffeomorphic? Is there some trick to do that without using the definition?

Comment: @Andrew_Paste I don't think so.

Comment: What a pity! It would be very useful! Thank you so much

Comment: I had a doubt. Could you please show me the expression of $f^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}$? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Andrew_Paste Sure. It's$$f^{-1}(y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }y=0\\\frac{\sqrt{1+4y^2}-1}{2y}&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: What a stupid question I asked. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I consider on $S^n\setminus\{N,S\}$ the atlas $\{(S^n\setminus\{N,S\},\varphi_N)\}$, where $\varphi_N$ is the stereographic projection from the north pole

$\varphi_N: S^{n}\setminus\{N,S\} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n,\ \ \ \ \  (y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}) \mapsto \frac{1}{1-y_{n+1}}(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, 
with
$\varphi_N^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  S^{n}\setminus\{N,S\}  ,\ \ \ \ \  v=(v_1,\ldots,v_{n}) \mapsto \frac{1}{1+\|v\|^2}(2v_1,\ldots,2v_{n},\|v\|^2-1)$.

On $S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ I take the atlas $\{(U_1,\varphi_1),(U_2,\varphi_2)\}$, where $U_1=S^{n-1}\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0,1)\}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $U_2=S^{n-1}\setminus\{(0,\ldots,0,-1)\}\times\mathbb{R}$ and

$\varphi_1: U_1 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n,\ \ \ \ \  (x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \mapsto \left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_{n}},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{1-x_{n}},x_{n+1}\right)$
$\varphi_2: U_2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n,\ \ \ \ \  (x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \mapsto \left(\frac{x_1}{1+x_{n}},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{1+x_{n}},x_{n+1}\right)$, with
$\varphi_1^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  U_1  ,\ \ \ \ \  (u,w)=(u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1},w) \mapsto \left(\frac{2u_1}{1+\|u\|^2},\ldots,\frac{2u_{n-1}}{1+\|u\|^2},\frac{\|u\|^2-1}{1+\|u\|^2},w\right)$
$\varphi_2^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  U_2  ,\ \ \ \ \  (u,w)=(u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1},w) \mapsto \left(\frac{2u_1}{1+\|u\|^2},\ldots,\frac{2u_{n-1}}{1+\|u\|^2},\frac{1-\|u\|^2}{1+\|u\|^2},w\right)$.

Now we take the map
$$\begin{array}{rccc}\psi\colon&S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&S^n\setminus\bigl\{N,S\bigr\}\\&(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})&\mapsto&\left(\frac{x_1}{\|x\|},\ldots,\frac{x_{n+1}}{\|x\|}\right)\end{array}$$
with
$$\begin{array}{rccc}\psi^{-1}\colon&S^n\setminus\bigl\{N,S\bigr\} &\longrightarrow& S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}\\&(y,z)=(y_1,\ldots,y_n,z)&\mapsto&\left(\frac{y_1}{\|y\|},\ldots,\frac{y_{n}}{\|y\|},\frac{z}{\|y\|}\right)\end{array}$$

Now we consider
$(\varphi_N\circ\psi\circ\varphi_1^{-1})(u,w)=(\varphi_N\circ\psi\circ\varphi_1^{-1})(u_1,\ldots,u_{n-1},w)=(\varphi_N\circ\psi)\left(\frac{2u_1}{1+\|u\|^2},\ldots,\frac{2u_{n-1}}{1+\|u\|^2},\frac{\|u\|^2-1}{1+\|u\|^2},w\right)=\varphi_N\left(\frac{1}{1+w^2}\left(\frac{2u_1}{1+\|u\|^2},\ldots,\frac{2u_{n-1}}{1+\|u\|^2},\frac{\|u\|^2-1}{1+\|u\|^2},w\right)\right)=\frac{1}{1+w^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{1+w^2}}\left(\frac{2u_1}{1+\|u\|^2},\ldots,\frac{2u_{n-1}}{1+\|u\|^2},\frac{\|u\|^2-1}{1+\|u\|^2}\right)$ that is $C^{\infty}$ since $1-\frac{w}{1+w^2}\neq0$ because the equation $w^2-w+1=0$ has no solution.

Similarly we prove that $\varphi_N\circ\psi\circ\varphi_2^{-1}$ and $\varphi_i\circ\psi^{-1}\circ\varphi_N^{-1}$ for $i=1,2$ are $C^{\infty}$, so we can conclude that $\psi$ it's a diffeomorphism, and it means that $S^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{n}\setminus\{N,S\}$.

Is it all right?